# looks like back reference is being treated as encoded char

Tags: regex, python-2.7

```
from urllib import quote_plus
import re
mac = "00:aa:aa:aa:aa:aa"
path = r"\api\{mac}\test"
print quote_plus(mac)
print(re.sub("(.*?)" + "{mac}"  + "(.*)", "\\1" + quote_plus(mac)+ "\\2", path))
```

This gives me response
`@%3Aaa%3Aaa%3Aaa%3Aaa%3Aaa\test`

though if I change `mac` to `aa:aa:aa:aa:aa:aa` then I get expected response
`\api\aa%3Aaa%3Aaa%3Aaa%3Aaa%3Aaa\test`

Any Idea what is happening here and how do I fix this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to fix your code, all you need to do is replace `"\\1"` with `"\\g<1>"` (unambiguous backreference).

The replacement pattern (after concatenation) contains `\100` at the beginning, which is in fact  an octal representation of `@`.

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/RNREtQ).

See [Python `re` help](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.sub) about unambiguous backreferences:

> In string-type *repl* arguments, in addition to the character escapes and backreferences described above, `\g<name>` will use the substring matched by the group named name, as defined by the `(?P<name>...)` syntax. `\g<number>` uses the corresponding group number; `\g<2>` is therefore equivalent to `\2`, but isn’t ambiguous in a replacement such as `\g<2>0`. `\20` would be interpreted as a reference to group 20, not a reference to group 2 followed by the literal character `'0'`. The backreference `\g<0>` substitutes in the entire substring matched by the RE.

Comment: The hidden mysteries of backslash and special characters.

Answer (score 2):

Why are you using regex? You can do it with string substitution:

```
from urllib import quote_plus

mac = "00:aa:aa:aa:aa:aa"
mac2 = "aa:aa:aa:aa:aa:aa"
path = r"\api\{}\test"
print path.format(quote_plus(mac))
print path.format(quote_plus(mac2))
```

Output:

```
\api\00%3Aaa%3Aaa%3Aaa%3Aaa%3Aaa\test
\api\aa%3Aaa%3Aaa%3Aaa%3Aaa%3Aaa\test
```

---

If you want to format with a variable name.

```
from urllib import quote_plus

mac = "00:aa:aa:aa:aa:aa"
mac2 = "aa:aa:aa:aa:aa:aa"
path = r"\api\{mac}\test"
print path.format(mac=quote_plus(mac))
print path.format(mac=quote_plus(mac2))
```

Comment: Thanks, I think I can get going with this approach, but this does not answer why re.sub is creating problem